# Facebook SDK. Invite friends to the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to choose one of more friends and send them an invite to my app.
I use `invitable_friends` method of Graph API to get a list of friends, who didn't install my app yet. Then I render my friends in the app UI. User choose friends and tap to send invitations.
And here's the problem.
I tried to use `FBSDKAppInviteDialog`, but I couldn't set specific users in its content. And the only one possibility to choose friends is to use facebook dialog, not custom view.

I tried to use `FBSDKGameRequestDialog`. Its content has a property `to` to set specific users, but the `FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate` methods are unreachable. And I'm not sure that using game request is the right way to invite friends to use my app.

Older Facebook SDK provided `[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:message:title:parameters:handler:]`. And this worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution of my problem. Using code like Dmitry Timoshenko has posted, `FBSDKGameRequestDialog` calls its `dealloc`, where it nilify his `_delegate`. That's why I didn't reach any `FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate` methods.
I made a strong `@property` for `FBSDKGameRequestDialog` and now I receive facebook user ids in `gameRequestDialog:didCompleteWithResults:`.

Answer (score 2):

I use it this way:

First, you get list of FB friends and store it in NSMutableArray:

```
- (void) getFriendsFromFB:(NSDictionary*)parameters invitable:(BOOL) invitable {
    NSString* graphPath = @"/me/friends";

    if (invitable) {
        graphPath = @"/me/invitable_friends";
    }

    FBSDKGraphRequest* request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:graphPath parameters:parameters];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection * connection, id result, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Facebook: error handling friend invite request at path %@: %@", graphPath, error.description);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Facebook: successfully handled friend request for graph path %@",graphPath);

            NSArray *friendArray = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

            for (NSDictionary* friendDict in friendArray) {

                FContact* contact = [[FContact alloc] initWithFaceBookID:friendDict[@"id"] name:friendDict[@"name"] avatarURL:friendDict[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"]];
                contact.hasMyGameInstalled = !invitable;
                [[FStorage sharedInstance].friends addObject:contact];
            }

            NSLog(@"Facebook contacts received: %lu contacts",(unsigned long)friendArray.count);

            if (!invitable) {
                NSLog(@"Facebook: making game");
                storage.currentGame = [[FGame alloc] initWithPreset];
                [storage.savedGames addObject:storage.currentGame];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"GameInfoUpdated" object:nil];
            }
        }

    }];
}
```

Now, I can display list of FB friends and let user choose whom to invite.
And when I have user selected, I'd propose a game to him:

```
- (void) proposeGameTo:(FContact*) contact{
    FBSDKGameRequestContent *gameRequestContent = [[FBSDKGameRequestContent alloc] init];

    // Look at FBSDKGameRequestContent for futher optional properties
    gameRequestContent.message = @"Let's play My brilliant game together";
    gameRequestContent.title = @"My custom invitation";
    gameRequestContent.to = @[contact.facebookID];
    gameRequestContent.actionType = FBSDKGameRequestActionTypeTurn;

    FBSDKGameRequestDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKGameRequestDialog alloc] init];
    dialog.frictionlessRequestsEnabled = YES;
    dialog.content = gameRequestContent;
    dialog.delegate = self;

    // Assuming self implements <FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate>
    [dialog show];
}
```

Comment: do you reach delegate methods calls? Me - no. So I can't get neither user ids (not invite tokens) nor request id

Comment: Which delegate methods do you mean? You don't really need delegates to get user id's, it's just a call with resulting block, that's it.

Comment: make a difference between temporary `invite_token`s and constant `user_id`s. `invitable_friends` returns `invite_token`s in `id` field. It's an alphanumeric string. `FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate`'s method `gameRequestDialog:didCompleteWithResults:` returns `user_id`s - numeric user identifiers.

Comment: I tried your code for inviting my friends and it worked. But my problem is that only a part of the players invited receive the notification. What can i do or check ?

Comment: Seems this is now up to FB settings for exact person who may allow/deny invitations.

Comment: it shows an error "use of undeclared identifier FContact"